# Toggle ListView Items style to List/Grid style on single ItemSource in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to switch ListView Items into List/Grid style in windows phone 8.1 (native xaml + c#) on a single Itemsource attached to Listview.
For reference see attached image.
[image]

Comment: you can keep both of the listview and the gridview in the xaml. turn on and off the visibility of the listview and the gridview from the c# code behind the xaml when required conditions are met.

Comment: is it sliverlight or win RT?

Comment: can you share you list view data template...xaml

Comment: here is the link to check DataTemplate of my listview.http://paste.ofcode.org/hPerLP5kDMtqqF5vGTmUWe

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different views as required. implement visibility converter here, to toggle between your views.

```
namespace MVVM1Test.Resources.Converters
{
    public class NotConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
    }
}
```